# how i display return value eg: phone number : balance [9222111555 : 150] in solidity

Tags: arrays, mapping, solidity

```
    //Owner to Phone
    mapping(address => uint256[]) public phones;
    // Phone to Balance
    mapping(uint256 => uint256) public balance;

function register(uint256 phone, uint256 Balance) public {
        _mint(msg.sender, phone);
        phones[msg.sender].push(phone);
        balance[phone] = Balance;
    }
     
    function details(address owner) public view returns(uint256[] memory){
        return (phones[owner]);
    }
```

When i call the function details it gives me return only no. those i have mint , but i want

{

"9222111888" : "150",

"9093164641" : "550",

}

Comment: Storing phone numbers on the block chain, smells like a lawsuit to me

Answer (score 0):

Not exact output, but if you want to return balances as well, you need to use struct.
for example

```
struct Data {
    uint256 number;
    uint256 balance;
}

...

function details(address owner) public view returns (Data[] memory data) {
    uint256[] memory ownerPhones = phones[owner];
    uint256 numPhones = ownerPhones.length;
    data = new Data[](numPhones);

    uint256 number;

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < numPhones; i++) {
        number = ownerPhones[i];
        data[i].number = number;
        data[i].balance = balance[number];
    }
}
```

Comment: hello, Satoshi Naoki sir, please see my image in your edited code ......

Comment: in your code, `balance[phone]` is not an array, but it's just `uint256`

Comment: hello, good morning sir, i have send 2 image in edited code 1st is code and 2nd where i'm stuck to return ......error show , please contribute to solve my error , thanks in advance

Comment: i have another idea , with the help of hash map , if i convert my mapping(userBalances) to string and pass in return .....have you any idea to convert mapping to string and return string ?? i'm trying if u have solution please contribute ....